# Armazenar dados em JSON no MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

Possuo uma base de dados em Mysql onde, a medida que o projeto vai sendo desenvolvido, o número de campos de algumas tabelas tem crescido exponencialmente.

A tabela Pessoas, por exemplo, possui campos relativos a documentos pessoais, endereço residencial, endereço profissional, dados pessoais, dados acadêmicos, etc.

```
'empresa' => 
array (size=6)
  'nome' => string 'Empresa Legal' (length=13)
  'funcao' => string '' (length=0)
  'rendimento' => string '' (length=0)
  'endereco' => 
    array (size=7)
      'cep' => string '' (length=0)
      'logradouro' => string '' (length=0)
      'numero' => string '' (length=0)
      'complemento' => string '' (length=0)
      'bairro' => string '' (length=0)
      'cidade' => string '' (length=0)
      'estado' => string '' (length=0)
  'telefone' => 
    array (size=2)
      'fixo' => string '' (length=0)
      'movel' => string '' (length=0)
  'email' => string '' (length=0)
```

Havia pensado em agrupar os dados em Json e armazenar cada grupo em um campo específico mas não tenho certeza se essa é uma boa prática ou se afeta a performance do banco de dados.

A minha dúvida é essencialmente sobre boas práticas em relação ao armazenamento dos dados, pois consigo manusear o JSON se problemas.

Caso esta não seja a melhor forma, aceito sugestões para estruturar esses dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Neste caso, você estaria fugindo da primeira forma normal. A normalização do banco de dados é essencial para garantir integridade e performance.

Portanto isso não seria recomendado neste caso que você está utilizando MySQL. Porém para este tipo de situação existem os banco de dados NoSQL, que se comportam exatamente desta maneira, armazenando coleções (como se fosse JSON) que não precisam seguir um esquema engessado.

Para ler mais sobre Normalização de Banco de Dados:
[Normalização de Dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados)

Para ler mais sobre NoSQL:
[NoSQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)
[MongoDB](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB)